# Solución integrar script.js de fronted un proyecto node.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, nodejs, ejs

estoy intentando vincular o integrar estos códigos

```js
const number = document.getElementById("number");
const device = document.getElementById("device");
const slider = document.getElementById("slider");
const random = (min, max) => {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
};

const interval = setInterval(() => {
  const offsetY = random(0, slider.offsetHeight - 20);
  requestAnimationFrame(() => update(offsetY));
}, 2000);

const update = (offsetY) => {
  const pos = Math.max(0, Math.min(slider.offsetHeight - 20, offsetY));
  slider.style.setProperty("--pos", `${pos}px`);
  const progress = Math.max(
    0,
    Math.min(100, 100 - (offsetY / slider.offsetHeight) * 100)
  );
  number.innerText = Math.round(progress * 0.42);
  device.style.setProperty("--progress", `${progress}%`);
};

let pointerdown = false;
slider.addEventListener("pointerdown", () => {
  pointerdown = true;
  clearInterval(interval);
});
slider.addEventListener("pointermove", ({
  offsetY
}) => {
  if (pointerdown) {
    update(offsetY);
  }
});
slider.addEventListener("pointerup", () => {
  pointerdown = false;
});

slider.addEventListener("pointerleave", () => {
  pointerdown = false;
  clearInterval(interval);
});
```

```css
@supports (background: paint(houdini)) {
     @property --progress {
         syntax: "<percentage>";
         inherits: true;
         initial-value: 0%;
    }
     @property --x {
         syntax: "<percentage>";
         inherits: true;
         initial-value: 0%;
    }
     @property --y {
         syntax: "<percentage>";
         inherits: true;
         initial-value: 0%;
    }
}
 :root {
     --c1: #00adff;
     --c2: #39d469;
     --c3: #ffeb00;
     --c4: #ff8100;
     --c5: #b50f0f;
     --surface: #fffeff;
     --on-surface: #636571;
     --outline: #000001;
     --background: #112;
     --v: 1;
}
 .thermostat {
     height: 24vmin;
     width: 100%;
     display: grid;
     grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
     gap: 1vmin;
     position: relative;
     place-items: center;
}
 .liquid {
     position: absolute;
     inset: 0;
     border-radius: 10vmin;
     overflow: hidden;
     isolation: isolate;
}
 .liquid .bg {
     position: absolute;
     inset: 0;
}
 .liquid .bg:before, .liquid .bg:after {
     content: "";
     position: absolute;
     inset: 0;
     --gp: calc(100% - var(--progress));
     background: linear-gradient(to bottom, var(--c5) calc(5% - var(--gp)), var(--c4) calc(25% - var(--gp)), var(--c3) calc(50% - var(--gp)), var(--c2) calc(75% - var(--gp)), var(--c1) calc(100% - var(--gp)));
     transform: translateY(calc(100% - var(--progress)));
     animation: wave 1s linear infinite;
     transition: all 0.3s linear;
     filter: saturate(0.65);
}
 .liquid .bg:after {
     transform: scaleX(-1) translateY(calc(100% - var(--progress)));
     opacity: 0;
     --o: 0.6;
     animation-delay: 0.55s;
}
 @keyframes wave {
     from {
         opacity: var(--o, 1);
         clip-path: polygon(100% 100%, 0% 100%, 0% 27.83%, 7.14% 28.61%, 14.29% 28.98%, 21.43% 28.9%, 28.57% 28.4%, 35.71% 27.49%, 42.86% 26.22%, 50% 24.65%, 57.14% 22.86%, 64.29% 20.95%, 71.43% 19%, 78.57% 17.12%, 85.71% 15.4%, 92.86% 13.92%, 100% 12.77%);
    }
     25% {
         clip-path: polygon(100% 100%, 0% 100%, 0% 17.77%, 7.14% 16.02%, 14.29% 14%, 21.43% 11.82%, 28.57% 9.58%, 35.71% 7.4%, 42.86% 5.38%, 50% 3.63%, 57.14% 2.23%, 64.29% 1.26%, 71.43% 0.76%, 78.57% 0.76%, 85.71% 1.26%, 92.86% 2.23%, 100% 3.63%);
    }
     50% {
         clip-path: polygon(100% 100%, 0% 100%, 0% 2.21%, 7.14% 1.34%, 14.29% 0.93%, 21.43% 1.01%, 28.57% 1.58%, 35.71% 2.6%, 42.86% 4.03%, 50% 5.8%, 57.14% 7.81%, 64.29% 9.97%, 71.43% 12.16%, 78.57% 14.28%, 85.71% 16.22%, 92.86% 17.88%, 100% 19.19%);
    }
     to {
         opacity: var(--o, 1);
         clip-path: polygon(100% 100%, 0% 100%, 0% 31.33%, 7.14% 32.11%, 14.29% 32.48%, 21.43% 32.4%, 28.57% 31.9%, 35.71% 30.99%, 42.86% 29.72%, 50% 28.15%, 57.14% 26.36%, 64.29% 24.45%, 71.43% 22.5%, 78.57% 20.62%, 85.71% 18.9%, 92.86% 17.42%, 100% 16.27%);
    }
}
 @keyframes b1 {
     from {
         --x: 50%;
         --y: 60%;
         opacity: 0;
    }
     50% {
         --x: 60%;
         --y: 45%;
         opacity: 1;
         transform: scale(1.1);
    }
     to {
         --x: 50%;
         --y: 30%;
         opacity: 0;
    }
}
 @keyframes b2 {
     from {
         --x: 50%;
         --y: 80%;
         opacity: 0;
    }
     50% {
         --x: 10%;
         --y: 55%;
         opacity: 1;
         transform: scale(1.1);
    }
     to {
         --x: 60%;
         --y: 30%;
         opacity: 0;
    }
}
 @supports (background: paint(houdini)) {
     .bubbles {
         position: absolute;
         inset: 0;
    }
     .bubbles:before {
         content: "";
         position: absolute;
         inset: 0;
         --x: 50%;
         --y: 80%;
         background: radial-gradient(0.2vmin at var(--x) var(--y), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) 4vmin, transparent 4vmin, transparent) center center no-repeat, radial-gradient(0.3vmin at calc(var(--x) * 1.9) calc(var(--y) * 1.9), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) 4vmin, transparent 4vmin, transparent) center center no-repeat;
         mix-blend-mode: soft-light;
         animation: b2 linear 3.5s infinite;
    }
     .bubbles:after {
         content: "";
         position: absolute;
         inset: 0;
         --x: 30%;
         --y: 60%;
         background: radial-gradient(0.2vmin at var(--x) var(--y), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) 4vmin, transparent 4vmin, transparent) center center no-repeat, radial-gradient(0.3vmin at calc(var(--x) * 1.2) calc(var(--y) * 1.5), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) 4vmin, transparent 4vmin, transparent) center center no-repeat;
         mix-blend-mode: soft-light;
         animation: b1 linear 6s infinite;
    }
}
 .glass {
     position: absolute;
     inset: 0;
     background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
     border-radius: 10vmin;
}
 .glass-container {
     height: 24vmin;
     width: 6vmin;
     border-radius: 10vmin;
     position: relative;
     border: 0.1vmin solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
     box-shadow: -1px 0.1vmin 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 1px 0.1vmin 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
 .glass-container:before {
     border-radius: 10vmin;
     content: "";
     position: absolute;
     --size: 2vmin;
     inset: calc(var(--size) * -1);
     border-left: var(--size) solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
     border-right: var(--size) solid rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.2);
     filter: blur(0.5vmin);
}
 .glass-reflection {
     pointer-events: none;
     mix-blend-mode: overlay;
     position: absolute;
     border-radius: 10vmin;
     overflow: hidden;
     inset: 0;
}
 .glass-reflection:before {
     content: "";
     position: absolute;
     inset: 0;
     background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)) no-repeat, linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)) no-repeat;
     background-size: 0.5vmin 19vmin, 1.8vmin 21vmin;
     background-position: 1vmin 3vmin, 3vmin 2vmin;
     filter: blur(0.4vmin);
}
 .glass-reflection:after {
     content: "";
     position: absolute;
     inset: 0;
     background: radial-gradient(4vmin 14vmin at 1vmin 20%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) 10%, transparent 50%, transparent), radial-gradient(2vmin 2vmin at 2vmin 5%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9), transparent, transparent), radial-gradient(7vmin 7vmin at 2vmin 5%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9), transparent, transparent);
}
 .number {
     font-size: 7vmin;
     font-weight: bold;
     color: #e8eaec;
     position: relative;
     text-shadow: -0.5vmin -0.5vmin 1vmin rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0.5vmin 0.5vmin 0.8vmin rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
     font-variant-numeric: tabular-nums;
}
 .number:after {
     content: "°";
     position: absolute;
}
 .slider {
     place-self: center;
     --gp: calc(100% - var(--progress));
     --pos: 0px;
     background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #333 var(--gp), white var(--gp));
     box-shadow: -0.1vmin 0 0 0.1vmin rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
     width: 0.1vmin;
     border-radius: 1vmin;
     height: 20vmin;
     position: relative;
}
 .slider:before {
     content: "";
     position: absolute;
     inset: -1vmin -2vmin;
}
 .slider:after {
     content: "";
     position: absolute;
     top: calc(10vmin * var(--gp) / 100);
     width: 3vmin;
     height: 3vmin;
     background: radial-gradient(30% 30% at 50% 50%, white, transparent), radial-gradient(70% 70% at 50% 50%, #f6f0f0, #bfc1cd), white;
     border-radius: 50%;
     transform: translate(-50%, var(--pos, 0));
     border-left: 0.1vmin solid white;
     box-shadow: -0.5vmin -0.5vmin 1vmin rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8), 0.5vmin 0.5vmin 1vmin rgba(26, 26, 26, 0.2);
}
 .device {
     background: transparent;
     width: 25svmin;
     aspect-ratio: 0.5454545455;
     border-radius: 4vmin;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
     gap: 2.5vmin;
     --progress: 100%;
     transform: scale(1.5);
}
 body {
     height: 100vh;
     width: 100vw;
     background: linear-gradient(135deg, #f7fbfc, #bcc7d3);
     display: grid;
     place-items: center;
     position: relative;
     font-family: "Inter", "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", sans-serif;
}
 body:after {
     content: "";
     position: absolute;
     inset: 0;
     background: url(https://assets.codepen.io/907471/noise.svg);
     mix-blend-mode: overlay;
     pointer-events: none;
}
 * {
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://codepen.io/konstantindenerz/pen/KKxvdPq.js"></script>
<div class="device" id="device">
  <div class="number" id="number">42</div>
  <div class="thermostat">
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="glass-container">
      <div class="glass"></div>
      <div class="liquid">
        <div class="bg"></div>
        <div class="bubbles"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="glass-reflection"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider" id="slider"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

en un proyecto node.js. El proyecto es sería el siguiente https://github.com/FaztWeb/first-node-express-app

¿Como podría implementarlo?

### intentos

index.html, y el css cada uno va en una carpeta, y están bien vinculados, pero el archivo js con ese script no sé en que carpeta colocarlo, y como implementarlo para que funcione. Lo estoy haciendo en el proyecto que adjunt

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: pues, index.html, y el css cada uno va en una carpeta, y están bien vinculados, pero el archivo js con ese script no sé en que carpeta colocarlo, y como implementarlo para que funcione. Lo estoy haciendo  en el proyecto que adjunté.

Answer (score 0):

Pasa los archivos HTML CSS y JS de tu pregunta a la carpeta public, (estos últimos 2 deben estar enlazados al HTML lógicamente). Quedaría así:

```
root
 |-> src
     |-> public
         |-> index.html
         |-> index.js
         |-> styles.css
```

De esta manera con el middleware 'static' podrías acceder a tu proyecto, por defecto este proyecto se serviría en la ruta '/':

```
app.use(express.static(join(__dirname, "public")));
```

Pero ya que tienes ocupada esa ruta con tu pagina 'first web node', cámbiale el nombre al endpoint de la misma para acceder tanto a la pagina principal como al HTML:

```
router.get("/main", (req, res) => { 
  res.render("index", { title: "First Web Node" });
});
```

Entonces la ruta http://localhost:3000 te llevara al documento HTML.

---

Si quieres mantener tu ruta '/' como la ruta de 'first web node', puedes servir el proyecto de Frontend en otra ruta, pasando un segundo parámetro al middleware 'static':

```
// static files
app.use(express.static(join(__dirname, "public")));
app.use('/mystaticfiles', express.static(join(__dirname, "public"))) // <- el front se servira con este endpoint
```

Entonces accediendo a *http://localhost:3000/mystaticfiles/* veras la pagina web si colocas la ruta en el navegador.